# can't find model on server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm having an odd problem: I have this code that I'm using exactly as-is on my local machine and on my dev server (ubuntu).

When I do an ajax call, it goes to the given URL and passes along some posts.  However, on the server it gives me an error 500.  After some investigating, I find that the model is not loading.  The weird thing is that on my local machine the code works fine.

Would this be a config problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might have used inconsistent case in your references to files or models. If  you refer to models/My_Model but the file is called models/my_model it will probably work on your mac or windows machine locally where file names are case-insensitive by default, but on the Ubuntu box file paths are probably case sensitive and those would then be different files. Other possibility is file permissions set incorrectly, though this is the less likely option.

How about posting some code and the relevant bit of the error log if this doesn't help.

Comment: nope, you were right.  I didn't have my first letter capitalized (I used 'searchModel' instead of something like 'Search_model').  Thanks for the help!!  Sometimes all it is is just a different perspective!